# Robocopy in c# not copying data

Tags: c#

My robocopy is not working..I have the code below and I am not getting any error.Could you please help?

```
            try
            {
            System.Diagnostics.Process p = new Process();

            p.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("/C ROBOCOPY {0} {1}",
                 sourceTextBox.Text , destinationTextBox.Text, "CopyFilesForm.exe");
            p.StartInfo.FileName = "CMD.EXE";

            p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;
            p.Start();
            p.WaitForExit();
            if (p.HasExited)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Copy Successful");
            }
        }

        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error. Please try closing the application and try again.");
            throw;
        }
```

Comment: try adding logging to robocopy so you can capture the output (`/LOG:c:\temp\robocopy.log`)

Comment: Also, I am using  FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog(); to get the selectedpath and then using this string as sourcetext and destinationtext. Could this be the problem?

Comment: Its not giving any output as well.

Comment: did you add the `/LOG:<filePath>` argument? robocopy always provides output (including arguments passed, etc), whether it's successful or not.

Comment: also, why are you using cmd to launch robocopy instead of just launching robocopy itself?

Comment: Thanks Rufus. Ok ,so I got it working with  a vertabim string using @"". What do I do if I have a textbox and its value changes all the time. How do i make it a vertabim string. I tried string sourceValue = "@\"" + sourceTextBox.Text + "\""; but it does not work.

Comment: what is the value in the text box that's giving you a problem? `TextBox.Text` should work fine for a file path.

Comment: the source directory in the text box is                                                         C:\Users\Nilay Bhima\Desktop\Galileo\6. GD unlock and the destination is      C:\Users\Nilay Bhima\Desktop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would bet you have a space in your destination path. Try encapsulate both source and destination path with quotes:

```
 p.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("/C ROBOCOPY \"{0}\" \"{1}\"",
             sourceTextBox.Text , destinationTextBox.Text, "CopyFilesForm.exe");
```

Also, just to clarity, the "CopyFilesForm.exe" argument is never used, but i Think it's just a debugging leftover?

Comment: I managed to get it work with a string source and destination path using @"". But I am now trying to use a textbox to get the source and destination but it does not work. I am get the source and destination using FolderBrowserDialog. Also I am copying directories now and not a single file.

Comment: @Nilay : I think Micael may be right - your paths have spaces in the names, so they should be quoted when passed to robocopy. try out this code.

Comment: Hi Micael and Rufus, Yes! This is working perfect. I never thought of this. THANK YOU!